# Select from last ID and older than it by 25 [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have posts which has fields (ID,title,date) What I'm looking for it to select rows order by date desc just limit for 25 records

lets say if we run that one it will show the last row with ID (600) like this:

(600,601,602,.....,625)

so I want after that to select another 25 records but min(id) before the last one (600) so it will be like this

(575,576,577,.....,599)

Comment: Fairly simple query, I think. What have you tried? Hints may be `LIMIT` and a suitable `WHERE` clause.

Comment: [This could give you a start:](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example consider that the first result gives the descending last five IDs.

```
SELECT idprocess FROM process ORDER BY idprocess DESC LIMIT 5 

248034
248033
248032
248031
248030
```

You could use a `SELECT` into a temporary table to mess with your result set's `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  The sub-query `LIMIT` should be the sum of the records you want back and how many you want skipped off the end.

```
SELECT t1.idprocess FROM 
    (SELECT idprocess FROM process ORDER BY idprocess DESC LIMIT 10) AS t1 
ORDER BY idprocess ASC LIMIT 5 

248025
248026
248027
248028
248029
```